# Creating a foreign constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, playframework

I am getting an error when installing an application using MySQL in a situation I have used often (with Play Framework!).

When applying the SQL I get the following error:

```
160909 16:03:26 Error in foreign key constraint of table knockadoonserver/action:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT "fk_action_switch_id" FOREIGN KEY ("switch_id") REFERENCES "switch" ("id")
```

But why is this? Is my database set wrong (this is a new install), as I have done this many times (in other applications)?

The full SQL is:

```
create table switch (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  name                          varchar(255),
  description                   varchar(255),
  gpio                          integer,
  turned_on                     BOOLEAN,
  device_id                     bigint,
  last_update                   datetime not null,
  add_date                      datetime not null,
  constraint pk_switch primary key (id)
);

create table sensor (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  serial                        varchar(255),
  name                          varchar(255),
  value                         float,
  main_sensor                   BOOLEAN,
  device_id                     bigint,
  last_update                   datetime not null,
  add_date                      datetime not null,
  constraint pk_sensor primary key (id)
);

create table action (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  message                       varchar(255),
  name                          varchar(255),
  type                          integer,
  start_time                    datetime,
  end_time                      datetime,
  daily                         BOOLEAN,
  min_value                     FLOAT,
  max_value                     FLOAT,
  disabled                      BOOLEAN,
  sensor_id                     bigint,
  switch_id                     bigint,
  last_update                   datetime not null,
  add_date                      datetime not null,
  constraint pk_action primary key (id)
);

alter table switch add constraint fk_switch_device_id foreign key (device_id) references device (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_switch_device_id on switch (device_id);

alter table sensor add constraint fk_sensor_device_id foreign key (device_id) references device (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_sensor_device_id on sensor (device_id);

alter table action add constraint fk_action_switch_id foreign key (switch_id) references switch (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_action_switch_id on action (switch_id);

alter table action add constraint fk_action_sensor_id foreign key (sensor_id) references sensor (id) on delete restrict on update restrict;
create index ix_action_sensor_id on action (sensor_id);
```

I left in the foreign contains on device, as that is a table created already, and doesn't seem a problem (I guess as it is prior). The SQL is:

```
create table device (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  name                          varchar(255),
  hostname                      varchar(255),
  ip_address                    varchar(255),
  last_connection               datetime,
  on_alarm                      boolean,
  on_silent                     boolean,
  alarm_whole_camp              boolean,
  map_xloc                      smallint,
  map_yloc                      smallint,
  last_update                   datetime not null,
  add_date                      datetime not null,
  constraint pk_device primary key (id)
);
```

It must be something small, but I have spend hours on this now.

The SQL above seems ok, so it must be something with how it is applied. I found this error:

[Edit:]

> ```
> 2016-09-09 16:03:26,823 [ERROR] from play.api.db.evolutions.DefaultEvolutionsApi in main - Error on rename
> ```
>
> of './database/#sql-47f_8e' to './database/action' (errno: 150)
>   [ERROR:1025, SQLSTATE:HY000]

The error as quoted in the beginning is the result of this error with "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;".

[Edit 2:]

```
| action | CREATE TABLE `action` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `daily` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `min_value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_value` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `disabled` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sensor_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `switch_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` datetime NOT NULL,
  `add_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `override_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `overrule_temp` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `overrule_time` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_action_switch_id` (`switch_id`),
  KEY `ix_action_sensor_id` (`sensor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_action_sensor_id` FOREIGN KEY (`sensor_id`) REFERENCES `sensor` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_action_switch_id` FOREIGN KEY (`switch_id`) REFERENCES `switch` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: It works fine on my 5.6.31

Comment: maybe make those 2 columns NOT NULL ?

Comment: Sometimes there is no switch or sensor associated with the action, so sometimes they are null.

Comment: I am running 5.5.50 on Raspbian.

Comment: oh ok ignore my answer. I will keep looking

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the constraint definition, assuming that the CREATE TABLE switch statement was successful. (It's a bit odd to see indexes on the foreign key columns being created after the constraint is added, since InnoDB will already automatically add the required index when a foreign key constraint is added. I'd expect the `create index` statement to fail with an error along the lines of "such an index already exists". I don't see how that index wouldn't be redundant.

Comment: I just ran all my queries one by one (instead of having them be applied all at the same time) and it works. So there must be something in the procedure the framework applies them.

Comment: I'm assuming that the default storage engine is InnoDB. If the `create index ` statements are successful, I suggest you take a look at the table definition, and see if you have redundant indexes. I would expect InnoDB to have created an index named the same as the foreign key constraint when the constraint was added. If the default storage engine is other than InnoDB, ...

Comment: I added some information. It must have to do with how everything is applied.

Comment: do the explicit ENGINE=INNODB as spencer says. Also the two RESTRICT clauses are superfluous

Comment: Gotta show lotsa love to those frameworks that save you all that time and effort... by making you spend hours researching a MySQL error which isn't really a MySQL error.

Comment: I wasted 30 minutes one time by assuming and omitting `ENGINE=INNODB` for a guy on an older build

Comment: @Drew:  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`  *never* omits the `ENGINE=`

Comment: that is true. `show create table action`

Comment: I added the output of 'show create table action'. I might just completely delete the database and start again.

Comment: Is 'action', the name I used for the table a reserved word in MySQL and not on H2 (which I use as a memory database during initial development)?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table action (
  id                            bigint auto_increment not null,
  message                       varchar(255),
  name                          varchar(255),
  type                          integer,
  start_time                    datetime,
  end_time                      datetime,
  daily                         BOOLEAN,
  min_value                     FLOAT,
  max_value                     FLOAT,
  disabled                      BOOLEAN,
  sensor_id                     bigint NOT NULL,
  switch_id                     bigint NOT NULL,
  last_update                   datetime not null,
  add_date                      datetime not null,
  constraint pk_action primary key (id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

make those 2 columns not null?